# Bootstrap : speed start and minimal setup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I'm on Debian Jessie, 32bit, editing with gEdit and trying to get BootStrap to work without an internet connexion. I went to [getbootstrap.com/getting-started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), downloaded the files from the left-most button, extracted the various folders (js, css, fonts) into a folder named bootstrap. 
I also created custom.css in the css folder and threw in a line

```
#qlksjhdf { color:#FF0000;}
```

Within this folder, I  created an HTML file. Then I copied some code from a working example. When I use the CDN links, all works fine, as expected, but when I replace the CDN with local linking such as "css/bootstrap.css", the styling disappears, although the H1 styling in "css/custom.css" works.

Do I need to "install" something or wouldn't just downloading and linking the files suffice ? And yes, I've also downloaded jQuery and linked it locally...

Comment: which version of JQuery and bootstrap are you using (locally and through CDN) ?

Comment: Hi do you have your override css file after bootstrap? And check all your links in source, are all the bootstrap files linked properly?

Comment: what is "this" folder you created the HTML within? if you're talking root, then "css/bootstrap.css" would not resolve, since you said you installed it in a bootstrap folder within root.  Use your debugging tools and find out if your CSS is not being found

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're using the right file path for the Bootstrap resources. If you put everything in a folder called bootstrap, you should be able to link the css file like this from your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Double check the path you are using to reference the bootstrap files. That is most likely the issue. If everything looks fine, can you add some code to the example or create a JS fiddle with the code you are working with?

Comment: This works ! Thanks ! Within the "origin" bootstrap folder is my html file and a css folder. Until now, I didn't know that I needed to include the name of the origin folder in which both my html file and my css folder sit. And therefore, when I insert a link to a css file in a css folder with the following     :     href="css/somefile.css"

   ... and never like you suggested :      href="bootstrap/css/somefile.css"

Comment: I re-checked because I can't actually believe it worked : and I can confirm that (adding the containing folder in the path) doesn't. I downloaded and extracted bootstrap all over again, rechecked my paths...and all went well.  I can confirm : just downloading and linking suffice. Can't retrace what I did that was wrong though... thanks for the replies. :-)